# How to create a file inside a folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have

```
fileUploadPath="d:/downloads";
```

and

```
entry.name='155ce0e4-d763-4153-909a-407dc4e328d0/63690689-e183-46ae-abbe-bb4ba5507f1a_MULTI_0_3/output/res2/res2.fcs';
```

when try to create res2.fcs file with following above path it shows gives me error, why it is not creating the folder structure?

code:

```
data.entries.forEach(entry => {
    console.log(entry.name);
    if (fs.existsSync(fileUploadPath)) {
        var sourceFilePath = fileUploadPath + '/' + entry.name;
        if (!fs.existsSync(sourceFilePath)) {
            fs.mkdir(sourceFilePath, {recursive: true }, (err) => {if (err) {
                    console.log("Failed :" + err);
                } else {
                    const fstream = fs.createWriteStream(require('path').format({dir: fileUploadPath, base: entry.name })); fstream.write('fileContent');
                    fstream.end();
                    fstream.on("finish", f => {
                        console.log(f)
                    });
                    fstream.on("error", e => {
                        console.log(e)
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('d');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('ssss')
    }
})
```

error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\downloads\626a69d18d2468c5082fc6e1\MULTI_1_2022-04-28_11-00-38\output\res1\res1.fcs'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\downloads\\626a69d18d2468c5082fc6e1\\MULTI__2022-04-28_11-00-38\\output\\res1\\res1.fcs'
```

Comment: Please clean up your code and fix the indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing file path to `.mkdir` instead of folder, so you should first create a folder, and then write the file

(as you're creating a folder that has the same name as the file, you should've got `EISDIR` error, instead of this one, which also says the file write didn't work)

use [path.dirname](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathdirnamepath) to extract folder and pass it to `.mkdir`:

```
// require path module at the top of the script
const path = require('path');


fs.mkdir(path.dirname(sourceFilePath), { recursive: true }, (err) => {
//...
```